# Translation for '--None--' value in lightning?

Tags: picklist, translation, schema

I am fetching the Labels & Values of a Picklist by using the following method

```
public static Map<String,String> getPickListValuesMap(string objName, string fieldName){

    Schema.SObjectType objType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName);
    Map<String,String> valuesLabels=new Map<String,String>();

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry ple : values){
        valuesLabels.put(ple.getLabel(), ple.getValue());

    }
    return valuesLabels;
}
```

As we know getLabel() returns the Label of the picklist value based on user's language. Here my problem is, Schema.PicklistEntry not retuning any label for '--None--'(Neither in English nor in any other language). So i have added '--None--' to the list & displayed on the UI. 

So Currently i am doing the translation for '--None--' by putting multiple if else statements in controller.js depending on the current User's language. As the languages are getting added this approach looks weird. So please suggest a better approach.

Comment: Why would the translation require multiple if-else statements? You could create a Custom Label with "---None---" in it and reference that label just once. Add as many translations to that label as you need.

Comment: Yes Charles, I had done this Yesterday. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**, if you need the field to look blank, you can use a zero width space as the "empty" value:

- Get the character on your clipboard [here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iLKwm)
- In Step 1 below, modify the "API Name" of the picklist value (you'll see it in saved picklist values on the field). Paste the zero width space in as the API name.
- In Step 2 below, paste that same zero width space into the default value of the field.

This is a hack, technically, but the field LOOKS empty.

**Original**

Try adding `---None---` as the first picklist value in the actual list of values and then make the first value the default one.

Then you can add all the translations you need.

Step 1:
[image: Adding new picklist value]

Step 2:
[image: Adding default value]

Comment: Thanks Harmer for your time, I have couple of questions 1) How does default value effects in the lightning. 2) If i add  '--None--' to picklist values, the  label and value would be '--None--' instead of only Label. But we need value as blank. How can it be achieved?

Comment: Ok, this is a trick, but you can use a zero-width space as the api name of the `---None---` field... get the space here: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iLKwm... I've updated the question.